# .gitignore sendo criado automaticamente pela IDE Eclipse

Tags: java, git, eclipse

Toda vez que eu crio um novo projeto Java no Eclipse o `.gitignore` é criado com a informação `/bin/` dentro do mesmo.

Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível eu configurar a IDE para não criar mais isso automaticamente?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360124/4319922

Comment: @StatelessDev amigo, posta a resposta para alimentar a base do pt.stackoverflow

Comment: @ErickLuz se o OP disser que aquilo resolveu o problema dele, crio a resposta.

Comment: @StatelessDev, grato pela ajuda, resolveu o meu problema!

Comment: Ok, @Diego . Criei uma resposta. Marque-a como correta, para futuros usuários saberem que ela é uma solução para o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível que a opção "Automatically ignore derived resources" dispare a criação/modificação  do `.gitignore`.

Uma solução para esse comportamento (ou seja, impedir a criação/alteração desse arquivo) seria:

> `Window → Preferences → Team → Git → Projects → Automatically ignore derived resources`

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360124/4319922)